# How to implement the delete method in a sqlite for android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to implement CRUD in the sqlite for android. I've implemented query and insert methods with join tables but I cannot find any info how can I implement a delete method from the multiple join tables?

Comment: Please provide more information. What exactly is it that you aren't able to do or don't understand how to do?

Comment: If you are hoping to delete rows from multiple tables using a single delete action, it is not possible.  You might be able to achieve the desired result using a delete and a trigger.  [Syntax for DELETE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).

Comment: Karakuri - In my app I have a listview, each item contains fields from different join tables. I want a user will be able to delete the item he wants. But in my database I have a big junction table that joins many tables together and I cannot use db.delete(table name,selection, selectionArgs) method as qbix has noticed. The question is how to delete my big junction table with all its join tables accordingly its ID and ID tapped item in a listview. I hope 
I have clearly described the problem. qbix I think you are right I have to use a delete and a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for every one helped me. I figured out two ways to solve my problem. First is ON DELETE CASCADE all fields associated with my junction table and other way is delete manually, i.e verify that every field of the junction table does't have any references.